# How to store cipher text when using Defuse to encrypt database data?

Tags: php, encryption

I am building a web application in PHP and have been tasked with encrypting all sensitive data that is stored in the database and obviously I need to be able to decrypt it when the application retrieves it back from the database.

After doing some research, it appears that I should use a prebuilt library to do this instead of trying to implement it myself. I have downloaded the Defuse encryption library from GitHub but I am struggling to get it to do what I want.

I have run the example code and that works fine, but in my application I am encrypting data before sending it to the database and I'm not sure where I should be storing the cipher text to allow me to decrypt it at a later date.

Can anyone give me some advice on whether Defuse is the correct tool for my needs (encryption needs to be at least AES-128) and how to store the cipher texts for decryption later.

I have also seen this script here which does not seem to use ciphers, just a secure key. Is this secure enough for storing sensitive data in a database?
https://www.warpconduit.net/2013/04/14/highly-secure-data-encryption-decryption-made-easy-with-php-mcrypt-rijndael-256-and-cbc/

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should set UTF-8 type in database for storing cipher text